# Writing to Global Memory Causing Crash in OpenCL in For Loop

Tags: opencl

One of my OpenCL helper functions writing to global memory in one place runs just fine, and the kernel executes typically. Still, when run from directly after that line, it freezes/crashes the kernel, and my program can't function.

The values in this function change (different values for an NDRange of 2^16), and therefore the loops change as well, and not all threads can execute the same code because of the conditionals.

Why exactly is this an issue? Am I missing some kind of memory blocking or something?

```c
void add_world_seeds(yada yada yada...., const uint global_id, __global long* world_seeds)
```

```c
for (; indexer < (1 << 16); indexer += increment) {
    long k = (indexer << 16) + c;
    long target2 = (k ^ e) >> 16;
    long second_addend = get_partial_addend(k, x, z) & MASK_16;

    if (ctz(target2 - second_addend) < mult_trailing_zeroes) { continue; }

    long a = (((first_mult_inv * (target2 - second_addend)) >> mult_trailing_zeroes) ^ (J1_MUL >> 32)) & mask;
    for (; a < (1 << 16); a += increment) {
        world_seeds[global_id] = (a << 32) + k; //WORKS HERE

        if (get_population_seed((a << 32) + k, x, z) != population_seed_state) { continue; }

        world_seeds[global_id] = (a << 32) + k; //DOES NOT WORK HERE
    }
}
```

```c
for (; a < (1 << 16); a += increment) {
    world_seeds[global_id] = (a << 32) + k; //WORKS HERE

    if (get_population_seed((a << 32) + k, x, z) != population_seed_state) { continue; }

    world_seeds[global_id] = (a << 32) + k; //DOES NOT WORK HERE
}
```

Comment: It's probably a bug (causing undefined behaviour) elsewhere in your code. I don't think you've provided enough information to debug this issue.

Comment: As it turns out, it appears one of the statements in my code while technically correct OpenCL causes an obscure bug with my hardware "AMD HSA Code Object Loading Failure"

Answer (score 0):

There was in fact a bug causing the undefined behavior in the code, in particular the main reversal kernel included a variable in the arguments called "increment", and in that same kernel I defined another variable called increment. It compiled fine but led to completely all over the wall wrong results and memory crashes.